# How to bind IP address to MAC in autoyast?

Tags: linux, ip, suse, sles

Is it possible to bind IP to physical address in autoyast config file? The following code doesn't do the trick:

```
     ...
<interfaces config:type="list">
      <interface>
        <bootproto>static</bootproto>
        <device>eth0</device>
        <ipaddr>ip_address_0</ipaddr>
        <hwaddr>aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff</hwaddr>
        <name>MY 1st NETWORK</name>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <startmode>auto</startmode>
        <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
      </interface>
      <interface>
        <bootproto>static</bootproto>
        <device>eth1</device>
        <ipaddr>ip_address_1</ipaddr>
        <hwaddr>ff:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee</hwaddr>
        <name>MY 2nd NETWORK</name>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <startmode>auto</startmode>
        <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
      </interface>
      <interface>
        <bootproto>static</bootproto>
        <device>eth2</device>
        <ipaddr>ip_address_2</ipaddr>
        <hwaddr>ee:ff:aa:bb:cc:dd</hwaddr>
        <name>MY 3rd NETWORK</name>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <startmode>auto</startmode>
        <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
      </interface>  
      <interface>
        <bootproto>static</bootproto>
        <device>eth3</device>
        <ipaddr>ip_address_3</ipaddr>
        <hwaddr>dd:ee:ff:aa:bb:cc</hwaddr>
        <name>MY 4th NETWORK</name>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <startmode>auto</startmode>
        <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
      </interface>        
      <interface>
        <bootproto>static</bootproto>
        <device>eth4</device>
        <ipaddr>ip_address_4</ipaddr>
        <hwaddr>cc:dd:ee:ff:aa:bb</hwaddr>
        <name>MY 5th NETWORK</name>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <startmode>auto</startmode>
        <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
      </interface> 
      <interface>
        <bootproto>static</bootproto>
        <device>eth5</device>
        <ipaddr>ip_address_5</ipaddr>
        <hwaddr>bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa</hwaddr>
        <name>MY 6th NETWORK</name>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <startmode>auto</startmode>
        <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
      </interface>         
    </interfaces>   
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AutoYaST specs](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_autoyast/data/createprofile_network.html), there should be a separate list of udev rules to map NICs' MAC addresses to the logical interface names.

E.g. your control file should be something like below:

```
<networking>
 <interfaces config:type="list">
   <interface>
     <bootproto>static</bootproto>
     <device>eth0</device>
     <ipaddr>ip.ad.dr.es</ipaddr>
     <hwaddr>aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff</hwaddr>
     <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
     <startmode>auto</startmode>
     <usercontrol>no</usercontrol>
   </interface>
 </interfaces>

 <net-udev config:type="list">
  <rule>
    <name>eth0</name>
    <rule>ATTR{address}</rule>
    <value>aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff</value>
  </rule>
 </net-udev>

</networking>
```